# Visual Studio. Как удалить лишние подключения к БД?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в Visual Studio удалить лишние подключения к БД? Физические пути на компьютере не совпадают, поскольку после папки Desktop отсутствуют другие папки с файлами, то есть, не существует такого пути на моём компьютере. Но тем не менее в ComboBox подключений к БД эти пути остались.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P.S. Решение найдено, большое спасибо человеку, который оставил комментарий внизу.**

В Visual Studio заходите в меню Вид —> Обозреватель объектов SQL Server (на английском вроде бы как так будет: View —> Sql Server Object Explorer).

Внизу я прикрепил картинку, как у меня выглядело в моём проекте. По нужным подключениям БД через контекстное меню просто удаляете необходимые объекты. Лично у меня во время удаления этих объектов не возникало никаких ошибок после этого.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очевидно, файлы этих БД были удалены в Проводнике Windows. Никогда так не делайте! БД нужно удалять, используя СУБД. Но что делать теперь? Я не знаю, насколько правилен такой способ, однако можно поступить так: создайте БД по указанному адресу (CREATE database), а затем удалите её (DROP database). Можно использовать Sql Server Object Explorer для этого.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Большое вам спасибо за подсказку, Помогло вот это — Sql Server Object Explorer. Я в Visual Studio зашёл в это окно и увидел весь этот ужас.